# Split table MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, split

Is it possible to split MySQL table horizontally? I mean the situation is this:

> I have table named Metals. Every metal has sub-group - iron,nickel,zinc and so on. I want this table to store all the metals but also to split their ID's. I want all products with Iron to start 1,2,3,4,5 as an ID but also products with nickel to start 1,2,3,4,5.

Is it possible or should I just split this into different tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0koI.png)

This is the example. Both of info to be in 1 table, the difference is sub-group (nickel,iron)

Comment: Could you add a sample row of table data to your example? Best in form of a table using "|" as separators.

Comment: added in description

Answer (score 0):

I think before you consider your database design you might want to consider normalisation methods and some general design of your structure you can read more about that [here](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)